# Get MP3 play length

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card

I'm creating a project where music gets played that is the same length or slightly shorter than the given time (minutes:seconds). For this I have a Sparkfun MP3 shield, which also has a microSD slot.

The issue is that I can't find a way to get the playtime of a given MP3 file. The only idea that I have is using the filesize and bitrate, but that would be horribly annoying for multiple bitrates.

Thanks in advance,

Michidez

Comment: You could try parsing the ID3 data of the MP3. Or just create a separate file containing the length. Or maybe encode the length in the filename (e.g. `mozart-154s.mp3`).